# neo4j and uni-directional relationship

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to `neo4j`. I've just read some information on this tool, installed it on Ubuntu and made a bunch of queries. And at this moment, I must confess, that I realy like it. However, there is something (I think very simple and intuitive), which I do not know how to implement. So, I created three nodes like so:

```
CREATE (n:Object {id:1}) RETURN n
CREATE (n:Object {id:2}) RETURN n
CREATE (n:Object {id:3}) RETURN n
```

And I created a hierarchical relationship between them:

```
MATCH (a:Object {id:1}), (b:Object {id:2}) CREATE (a)-[:PARENT]->(b)
MATCH (a:Object {id:2}), (b:Object {id:3}) CREATE (a)-[:PARENT]->(b)
```

So, I think this simple hierarchy should look like this:

```
(id:1) 
      -> (id:2)
               -> (id:3)
```

What I want now is to get a path from any node. For example, if I want to have a path from node (id:2), I will get (id:2) -> (id:3). And if I want to get a path from node (id:1), I will get (id:1)->(id:2)->(id:3). I tried this query:

```
MATCH (n:Object {id:2})-[*]-(children) return n, children
```

which I though should return a path (id:2)->(id:3), but unexpectedly  (just for me) it returns (id:1)->(id:2)->(id:3). So, what I'm doing wrong and what is the right query to use?

Comment: I've seen a lot of comments here and there, and I really wonder why people are asking about how to create bidirectional relationship. Whereas, I had to do nothing to have this bidirectional relationship. But at the same time I do not know how to create unidirectional relationship

Comment: Hm. It seems like I cracked it. I replaced `-` with `->` in the last query: `MATCH (n:Object {id:2})-[*]->(children) return n, children` and now it works.

Comment: But if someone could write a solid answer, describing how to create bi- and uni-directinal relationship and how to query them, that would be great and deserve +100500 of reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All relationships in neo4j are directed.  When you say `(n)-[:foo]->(m)`, that relationship goes only one way, from `n` to `m`.

Now what's tricky about this is that you can navigate the relationship both ways.  This doesn't make the relationship bi-directional, it never is -- it only means that you can look at it in either direction.

When you write this query: `(n:Object {id:2})-[*]-(children)` you didn't put an arrow head on that relationship, so `children` could refer to something either downstream or upstream of the node in question.

In other words, saying `(n)-[:test]-(m)` is the same thing as matching both `(n)<-[:test]-(m)` **and** `(n)-[:test]->(m)`.

So `children` could refer to the ID 1 object or ID 2 object.

Comment: `Now what's tricky about this is that you can navigate the relationship both ways. This doesn't make the relationship bi-directional, it never is -- it only means that you can look at it in either direction.` I think, tutorials and documentation presenting examples of how to create relationship should be prefaced with these words.

Answer (score 1):

## Returning only children

To directly answer your question,

Your query

```
MATCH (n:Object {id:2})-[*]-(children) return n, children
```

matches not only relationships **FROM** `(n {id:2})` **TO** its children, but also relationships **TO** `(n {id:2})` **FROM** its parents.

You need to additionally specify the direction that you'd like. This returns the results you expect:

```
MATCH (n:Object {id:2})-[*]->(children) return n, children
```

---

## Issues with the example

I'd like to answer your comment about uni-directional and bi-directional relationships, but let's first resolve a couple of issues with the example.

### Using correct labels

Let's revisit your example:

```
(:Object {id:1})-[:PARENT]->(:Object {id:2})-[:PARENT]->(:Object {id:3})
```

There's no point to using labels like `:Object`, `:Node`, `:Thing`. If you really don't care, don't use a label at all!

In this case, it looks we're talking about people, although it could easily also be motherboards and daughterboards, or something else!

Let's use People instead of Objects:

```
(:Person {id:1})-[:PARENT]->(:Person {id:2})-[:PARENT]->(:Person {id:3})
```

### IDs in Neo4j

Neo4j stores its own IDs of every node and relationship. You can retrieve those IDs with `id(nodeOrRelationship)`, and access by ID with a `WHERE` clause or by specifying them as a start point for your match. `START n=node(2) MATCH (n)-[*]-(children) return n, children` is equivalent to your original query `MATCH (n:Object {id:2})-[*]-(children) return n, children`.

Let's, instead of IDs, store something useful about the nodes, like names:

```
(:Person {name:'Bob'})-[:PARENT]->(:Person {name:'Mary'})-[:PARENT]->(:Person {name:'Tom'})
```

### Relationship ambiguity

Lastly, let's disambiguate the relationships. Does `PARENT` mean "is the parent of", or "has this parent"? It might be clear to you which one you meant, but someone unfamiliar with your system might have the opposite interpretation.

I think you meant "is the parent of", so let's make that clear:

```
(:Person {name:'Bob'})-[:PARENT_OF]->(:Person {name:'Mary'})-[:PARENT_OF]->(:Person {name:'Tom'})
```

---

## More information about uni-directional and bi-directional relationships in Neo4j

Now that we've taken care of a few basic issues with the example, let's address the directionality of relationships in Neo4j and graphs in general.

There are several ways we could have expressed the relationships this example. Let's look at a few.

### Undirected/bidirectional relationship

Let's abstract the parent relationship that we used above, for the purposes of discussion:

```
(bob)-[:KIN]-(mary)-[:KIN]-(tom)
```

Here the relationship `KIN` indicates that they are related but we don't know exactly who is the parent of whom. Is Tom the child of Mary, or vice-versa?

Notice that I didn't use any arrows. In the graph pseudo-code above, the `KIN` relationship is a bidirectional or undirected relationship.

Relationships in Neo4j, however, are always directional. If the `KIN` relationship was really how you wanted to track things, then you'd create a directional relationship, but always ignore the direction in your `MATCH` queries, e.g. `MATCH (a)-[:KIN]-(b)` and not `MATCH (a)-[:KIN]->(b)`.

But is the `KIN` relationship really the best way to store this information? We can make it more specific. Let's go back to the `PARENT_OF` relationship that we were using earlier.

### Directed/unidirectional relationship

Back to the example. We know that Bob is the parent of Mary who is the parent of Tom:

```
(bob)-[:PARENT_OF]->(mary)-[:PARENT_OF]->(tom)
```

Obviously, the corollary of this is:

```
(bob)<-[:CHILD_OF]-(mary)<-[:CHILD_OF]-(tom)
```

Or, equivalently:

```
(tom)-[:CHILD_OF]->(mary)-[:CHILD_OF]->(bob)
```

So, should we go ahead and create both the `PARENT_OF` and the `CHILD_OF` relationships between our (bob), (mary) and (tom) nodes?

The answer is no. We can pick one of those relationships, whichever best models the idea, and still be able to search both ways.

Using only the `:PARENT_OF` relationship, we can do

```
MATCH (mary {name:'Mary'})-[:PARENT_OF]->(children) RETURN children
```

to find the children, or

```
MATCH (mary {name:'Mary'})<-[:PARENT_OF]-(parents) RETURN parents
```

to find the parents, using (mary) as the starting point each time.

---

For more information, [see this fantastic article from GraphAware](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2013/10/11/neo4j-bidirectional-relationships.html)

Comment: Greate answer! Thank you, sir!

Comment: @Jacobian hope it helps.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I don't agree with your edits. Being a very long answer, it's crucial to separate into sections such that readers can skip to the relevant sections. Unfortunately the header styles are very similar and don't provide a substantial enough visual cue for different sections, otherwise the headers would be enough. While something like having code formatted as,  well, code, is universally accepted as an edit that should be made to questions and answers across SO, no such standard exists for spacing. What you've effectively done here is apply YOUR preferred style to this answer.

Comment: Excuse me? Complain, but don't try and point fingers. If you didn't like it, then fix it or rollback (as you did). Your comments comes out as aggressive to me.

Comment: @Zizouz212 It may be a little aggressive, sorry for that. I don't agree with your edits and I'm explaining why -- I'm not just going to rollback your changes without discussing them. Please explain while you feel that the spacing was excessive in light of my comment above.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I did not rollback your changes, I simply implemented your suggestion of horizontal lines, but I still feel that it is worse than the original.

Comment: @Zizouz212 did you downvote because you were unhappy with my comments about your edits?